# Printing selective fields following 1st column instructions

Tags: awk

Suppose I have a file in which I'd like to simultaneously print different `awk` commands following the first column instuctions, without messing up the original file (as it would happen with two separate prints):

File:

```
End 1st 2nd 3rd
Fin 1st 2nd 3rd
```

I'd like to combine the following commands into a one-liner:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^E/ {print $2}'
awk '$1 ~ /^F/ {print $3}'
```

To obtain the following output:

```
End 1st
Fin 2nd
```

**EDIT**
What I meant by saying "messing up the original file":

File 1:

```
E1   NAME1 LASTNAME1
FA   22   1992         #age, year
FC   UK   London       #country, city
FJ   IT   HP           #job, company
E2   NAME2 LASTNAME2
FA   25   1989        
FC   CH   Geneva      
FJ   CS   SIB
```

Now, if I run two separate awk prints, I won't be able to match the information in File 3 with the names of File 2 (especially if the number of `^F` fields are not of the same number):

`awk '$1 ~ /^E/ {print $2}' File 1 > File 2`

Output (File 2):

```
NAME1
NAME2
```

`awk '$1 ~ /^F/ {print $3}' File 1 > File 3`

Output (File 3):

```
1992        
London       
HP           
1989        
Geneva      
SIB
```

But, If I join them (as suggested in the answers) I'll be able to have something like this:

Expected output:

```
NAME1
1992        
London       
HP  
NAME2
1989        
Geneva      
SIB
```

Comment: In what way does two separate prints "mess up" the original file? What's wrong with simply doing `awk '$1 ~ /^E/ {print $1,$2}; $1 ~ /^F/ {print $1,$3}'`?

Comment: I meant, if I had multiple `^F` lines (let's say "descrption lines") belonging to a same `^E` line (let's say, an "identifier"), and I performed two separate `awk`, I would end up with two well written files, but I wouldn't be able to distinguish the `^F` lines belonging to a given `^E` line.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example? The example in your question does not seem to be sufficient to illustrate what you want.

Comment: I think I know what he means: If he does the first `awk` commando, he'll just get `End` lines. The following `Fin` lines, which are related to the `End` lines, are excluded in this search and therefor the correlation between both types is lost. So he needs an `awk` command that prints them in order.

Comment: Exact, @polym. That's what I meant. However, I joined an edit to my question, I hope it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '$1 ~ /^E|^F/ {if ($1 == "End") print $1" "$2; if ($1 == "Fin") print $1" "$3}'
```

or

```
awk '/^End/{print $1" "$2}/^Fin/{print $1" "$3}'
```

(thanks to [Jidder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146557/printing-selective-fields-following-1st-column-instructions#comment-237192))

Should work.

Comment: A lot of that code is redundant, if `$1="End"` then $1 must start with E so the first argument is not needed. This could be reduced to  `awk '/^End/{print $1" "$2}/^Fin/{print $1" "$3}'` whilst doing the exact same comparisons

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^E/ {print $1,$2;next};$1 ~ /^F/ {print $1,$3}' file
```

Comment: What does the `next` do?

Comment: @polym I guess it's effectively a short-circuit logic operator (no need to `~ /^F/` if you've already matched `/^E/`)

Comment: @steeldriver Oh so like a `continue` in C? Ok that makes sense.

Comment: From the man page of awk: `next # skip remaining patterns on this input line`

Comment: With the hat symbol it is redundant specifying $1 as it will be the first character on the line so `$1 ~ /^E` is equivelant to `/^E/`

Comment: @Jidder they're not exactly equivalent - with the default `FS`, awk will trim leading whitespace so `$1` may be equal to `End` yet `$0` equals `___End` for example [EDIT: stupid comment markdown won't let me post leading whitepsace in a `code` sequence].

Comment: @steeldriver I realise that but in this case(given OPs examples) it is at the start of the line and so it is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
awk '/^F/{$2=$3}NF=(NF-2)' file
```

If you want to match E as well(if there are other things in the file)

```
awk 'a=/^F/{$2=$3}{x=/^E/}(x||a)&&NF=(NF-2)' file
```

Answer (score 2):

For Expected output,

```
awk '/^E/{$0=$2} /^F/{$0=$3}1' file
```

If you want to print first field as well,

```
awk '/^E/{$0=$1 FS $2} /^F/{$0=$1 FS $3}1' file
```